# Pass a variable to an ajax function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass a variable to a javascript function, but I'm not sure what's going on as I am primarily a PHP person.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction( str){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            document.getElementById("emailconfirm").innerHTML= ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "Atest.php?Email="+str, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

//-->
</script>
```

the form

```
<form name='myForm'>

    <input name="email"   id="email"type="text" />
    <input name="button" onclick="ajaxFunction(document.getElementById('email').value" type="button" />
</form>
```

I wanna be able once the button get clicked, the email text input will be passed to the javascript function.

Comment: Why not just pass in the ID and do the lookup in the function? Much cleaner. But sure, you can pass whatever you want to the function.

Comment: Syntax error in you `onclick` attribute, missing `)`

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but I feel I should point you to JQuery. Of course it is good to know the basics, but once you found out the simplicity (and browser-independance) of JQuery Ajax requests, you will say 'screw you' to knowledge about underlaying technologies. ;)

Comment: You can always move the `document.getElementById('email').value` into the ajaxFunction()

Comment: @Nicosunshine Exactly 3 seconds! Great. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol -- ajax requests are one of the most cross-platform things out there once you have the right object.  Using jQuery /just/ for ajax is like using a steam shovel to plant a single flower.  There are far simpler wrappers that are just as nice, if not more nice, to use.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Of course they are cross-platform. I was talking about cross-browser. These 25 lines of code of execting the request and processing the response can be written in a single and quite sensible line of JQuery. If an Ajax request is really the only thing you're going to do with Javascript, there are simpler wrappers indeed, but even in the simple code of the question, there's DOM manipulation, one of the key features of JQuery. I'm not saying you have to switch, but you can't deny it makes sense to at least check out the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost perfect, just a few things:

You missed a `)` in your `onclick` event. Just add it to the end and it should work.

You don't need all that `try..catch` stuff, unless you need to support Internet Explorer 6, so you can just get rid of it and leave `ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()`.