# Ajax submit multivalues

Tags: javascript

why is my ajax function not submitting both values with the get method

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction( ){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            document.getElementById("emailconfirm").innerHTML= ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "Atest.php?<?php echo $PDFPassingArray ?>?Email="+ document.getElementById("email").value, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

I want the function to submit the array $pdfpassingArray, which is an html_build_query  and the Email elemment id from the form. currently I can only reviece the $pdfPassingarray values,  but not the Email values. so my question, did I do this part right

```
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "Atest.php?<?php echo $PDFPassingArray ?>?Email="+ document.getElementById("email").value, true);
```

my form

```
       <form name='myForm'>

    <input name="email"   id="email"type="text" />
    <input name="button" onclick="ajaxFunction()" type="button" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is this really part of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270099/pass-a-variable-to-an-ajax-function)?

Answer (score 3):

You have two `?`s in your URL string,

it should be in the form `url.php?a=1&b=2`